# moving from async false to async true

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-mobile

Hi so I have a piece of code that run quite a few times

Loader.load('data/map.json')

the idea is I can pass in any json file and the loader will deal with it

so here is the loader in async false format

```
  var Loader = {
    basePath: '',
    cache: {},
    load: function(name) {
        if(typeof this.cache[name] == 'undefined') {
            var loadUrl = (this.basePath == '') ? name : this.basePath + '/' + name;
            var parameters = {

                url: loadUrl,
                dataType: 'json',
                async: false,
                context: this,
                success: function(data) {
                    this.cache[name] = data;
                }
            };

            $.ajax(parameters);
        }
        return this.cache[name];
   }
};
return Loader;
```

but this is in async false format and I need to get this to async true format to work better with jQuerymobile so with some help on here I managed to get it to a point where its async

```
var data = AsyncLoader.load('data/map.json').done(function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
            console.log("complete");

        }).fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {

            console.log("an error has occurred");

        }).always(function(jqXHR, textStatus) {
            console.log("running");
        });
```

this call the asynloader

```
function($) {
var AsyncLoader = {
    basePath: '',
    cache: {},
    load: function(name) {
        if(typeof this.cache[name] == 'undefined') {
            var loadUrl = (this.basePath == '') ? name : this.basePath + '/' + name;
            var parameters = {
                beforeSend: function() { $.mobile.showPageLoadingMsg(); },
                complete: function() {$.mobile.hidePageLoadingMsg(); },
                url: loadUrl,
                dataType: 'json',
                async: true,
                context: this,
                success: function(data) {
                    this.cache[name] = data;
                }
            };

            $.ajax(parameters);
        }

        return this.cache[name];
    }
};

return AsyncLoader;
```

the problem is to make this work I need to return $.ajax(parameters) rather than return this.cache[name]; otherwise I get a javascript error.. the problem is if I change it to get $.ajax(parameters) when I load in maps.json for a second time it doesn't get the data from the this.cache it will load the json file again which is useless

can anyone help

thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

`$.ajax` returns [a `Deferred` object](http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/). You, too, can return your own `Deferred` object. Your new code might look a little like this:

```
load: function(name) {
    // Is the object already in the cache?
    if(Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(this.cache, name)) {
        // Yes! Return a Deferred that's already been resolved.
        return jQuery.Deferred().resolve(this.cache[name]);
    }else{
        // No! We have to load it. Let's still use our own Deferred, though:
        var deferred = jQuery.Deferred();

        // There's our Deferred. Now let's load it.
        jQuery.ajax({
            // ...
        }).done(function(data) {
            // We loaded it successfully!
            // Add it to our cache and resolve the Deferred.
            this.cache[name] = data;
            deferred.resolve(data);
        }).fail(function() {
            // Fail! Pass the failure on to our deferred.
            deferred.reject.apply(deferred, arguments);
        });

        // We've started the AJAX request. Now return our Deferred.
        return deferred;
    }
}
```

Comment: I have added more below.. couldnt add it here because of the formatting

Comment: @Dan: I can't immediately see any reason why it wouldn't work. Perhaps you can set a breakpoint inside of success to see that `this.cache[name]` is getting set correctly and inside of `load` to see that `this.cache[name]` is getting retrieved correctly.

Comment: @Dan: There may be no error, but when you set breakpoints there, does it look like the appropriate thing is happening?

Answer (score 0):

hmm, this isnt quite working..

if I use this

collection

```
var data = AsyncLoader.load('data/map.json').done(function(data) {

    var models = [];
    $.each(data.data.locations, function() {
        // RESERVED WORDS YO
        if(this['delete'] == 1) {
            return;
        }

        models.push(new MapLocationModel(this));

    });
    $t.reset(models);

});
```

async loader

```
function($) {
var AsyncLoader = {
    basePath: '',
    cache: {},
    load: function(name) {
        if(typeof this.cache[name] == 'undefined') {

            console.log("not cached");

            var deferred = jQuery.Deferred();
            var loadUrl = (this.basePath == '') ? name : this.basePath + '/' + name;
            var parameters = {
                beforeSend: function() { console.log("d"); },
                url: loadUrl,
                dataType: 'json',
                async: true,
                context: this,
                success: function(data) {
                    this.cache[name] = data;
                    deferred.resolve(data);
                }
            };

            $.ajax(parameters);
            return deferred;


        } else {

        console.log("cached");

        return jQuery.Deferred().resolve(this.cache[name]);

        }

    }
};

return AsyncLoader;
```

I will load in the map data multiple times and will never take it from the cache..

If however I change to async false in the above it works fine, but i need async to be true

Thanks

Comment: You are being defeated by the changing context of `this`. Try (a) adding `var that = this;` immediately after `load: function(name) {`, and (b) changing `this.cache[name]` to `that.cache[name]`.

Answer (score 0):

Two suggestions :

- Avoid `this` to refer to `AsyncLoader`
- Test for existence of an obhject property with `Object.hasOwnProperty()` rather than `typeof .... == 'undefined'`.

JS:

```
function($) {
    var AsyncLoader = {
        basePath: '',
        cache: {},
        load: function(name) {
            var dfrd = $.Deferred();
            if(!AsyncLoader.cache.hasOwnProperty(name)) {
                var loadUrl = (AsyncLoader.basePath == '') ? name : AsyncLoader.basePath + '/' + name;
                $.ajax({
                    beforeSend: function() { console.log("d"); },
                    url: loadUrl,
                    dataType: 'json',
                    async: true,
                    success: function(data) {
                        AsyncLoader.cache[name] = data;
                        dfrd.resolve(data);
                    }
                });
            }
            else {
                return dfrd.resolve(AsyncLoader.cache[name]);
            }
            return dfrd.promise();
        }
    };
    return AsyncLoader;
...
}(jQuery);
```

**Notes**

Whereas it would be possible for `AsyncLoader.load()` to return the data directly when it is already cached, this is not the case when the data needs to be obtained from the server; reason being that the server response is asynchronous. What's needed is a mechanism by which any expression that calls `AsyncLoader.load()`, can receive the data in exactly the same way, regardless of whether `AsyncLoader.load()` obtains the data from cache or from the server.

So in the code above, `AsyncLoader.load()` doesn't attempt to return the data, at least not in the conventional sense; instead, it returns a "promise", which is resolved either immediately if the required data is already available from cache, or later when the server responds.

In both cases, the value passed to `dfrd.resolve(...)` becomes available within the scope where `AsyncLoader.load()` is called, as an argument of a function specified in a `.done()` (or `.always()` or `.then()`) method, called on the returned promise (typically by method chaining).

For example :

```
AsyncLoader.load('myName').done(function(data) {
    console.log(data);
    //do wheatever else is necessary with `data` here.
});
```

Thus, the objective is achieved. By returning a promise (created within `AsyncLoader.load()`), the required data is made available outside the scope of `AsyncLoader.load()`, in exactly the same way, regardless of whether it was plucked from cache or freshly received from the server.

Expressions that call `AsyncLoader.load()` are completely unaware of whether the data was from cache or not, but must always be written in the correct way to receive data via the returned promise.

Comment: Thanks, I am guessing you mean return dfrd.promise(); and not return deferred.promise() as deferred is undefined...

Comment: also is this true?

When you use async:true you cannot define a function that returns the response of an ajax call. Whatever you want to do with the response data returned from an asynchronous ajax call must be done within the success or complete callback.

Your setup can only work if async:false.

Comment: Q1: Dan, yes you're right `return dfrd.promise() is correct.`

Comment: Q2: `async:false` should only be used in very exceptional circumstances - close to never. Yes, it's true that with `async:false` you can't return the server's data in the conventional way. However, it's not true that the code above will only work with `async:false`. See my added note for more details.

Comment: so weird it it never loads the file from cache.. its always loads in the json file never uses the cached on

Comment: If, after checking your code against my notes above, data is still always obtained via ajax, then you need to investigate - is it never cached, or is it cached but never retrieved from cache?

Comment: I think its being added to the cache and then never retireved from that if async = true

Comment: Dan, don't *think* - you've got to *know*. Devise a test that tells you for sure. And stop worrying about async, which cannot realistically be anything other than true.